# How to use the contrast function in ebayes for making different comparisons

Tags: rna-seq, limma

The design matrix i have is this I would like to know how to use they way its done in deseq2 where we can use the contrast function to make particular comparison

The code im running to make differential testing is this

```
tcgaGlm = lmFit(as.matrix(tcgaExpr), design = tcgaDesign) 
tcgaGlm = eBayes(tcgaGlm)
```

Now I will show the part of the data frame and the question Im trying to ask

```
head(tcgaDesign)
             Offset CEBPA DNMT3A FAM5C FLT3_ITD FLT3_TKD IDH1 IDH2 KIT KRAS NPM1 NRAS PHF6 PTPN11 RAD21 RUNX1 SMC1A SMC3 STAG2 TET2 TP53 U2AF1 WT1
TCGA-AB-2803      1     0      0     0        0        0    0    0   0    0    0    0    0      0     0     0     0    0     0    0    0     0   0
TCGA-AB-2805      1     0      0     0        0        0    0    1   0    0    0    0    0      0     0     1     0    0     0    0    0     0   0
TCGA-AB-2806      1     0      0     0        0        0    0    0   0    0    0    0    0      0     0     0     0    0     0    0    0     0   0
TCGA-AB-2807      1     0      0     0        0        0    0    1   0    0    0    0    0      0     0     1     0    0     0    0    0     0   0
TCGA-AB-2808      1     1      0     0        0        0    0    0   0    0    0    1    0      0     0     0     0    0     0    0    0     0   0
TCGA-AB-2810      1     0      0     0        0        0    0    1   0    0    1    0    0      0     0     0     0    0     0    0    0     0   0
               complex  minus5_5q   minus7q  plus8_8q     plus21    t_15_17     t_8_21 inv16_t16_16
TCGA-AB-2803 0.0000000 0.00000000 0.0000000 0.0000000 0.00000000 1.00000000 0.00000000   0.00000000
TCGA-AB-2805 0.0000000 0.00000000 0.0000000 0.0000000 0.00000000 0.00000000 0.00000000   0.00000000
TCGA-AB-2806 0.0000000 0.00000000 0.0000000 0.0000000 0.00000000 0.00000000 1.00000000   0.00000000
TCGA-AB-2807 0.1410256 0.08974359 0.1217949 0.1153846 1.00000000 0.09615385 0.04487179   0.04487179
TCGA-AB-2808 0.0000000 0.00000000 0.0000000 0.0000000 0.00000000 0.00000000 0.00000000   0.00000000
TCGA-AB-2810 0.1410256 0.08974359 0.1217949 0.1153846 0.05063291 0.09615385 0.04487179   0.04487179
```

Here if I have to make a comparison between CEBPA vs DNMT3A mutation in samples which carries CEBPA mutation and other which carries DNMT3A what or how should I do it.

To begin with I followed this [manual](https://www.bioconductor.org/packages/devel/bioc/vignettes/limma/inst/doc/usersguide.pdf) I m still not sure once you run the model do i need to form a design matrix which comprises of sample which contain mutation in CEBPA and DNMT3A ? or I can go ahead with this experimental design

```
dput(tcgaDesign)
structure(c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 
1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 
0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 
0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 
1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 
1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 
0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 
1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 
0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 
0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 
1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 
0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 
0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 
1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 
0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 
1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 
1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 
0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 
1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 
0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.141025641025641, 
0, 0.141025641025641, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0.141025641025641, 0, 0, 0, 0.141025641025641, 0, 0, 
0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0.141025641025641, 0.141025641025641, 0.141025641025641, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0.141025641025641, 0, 0, 0.141025641025641, 1, 0, 
1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0.141025641025641, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 
0, 0, 0, 0.141025641025641, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0.141025641025641, 
0, 0, 1, 0.141025641025641, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 
1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0.141025641025641, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
1, 0, 0.141025641025641, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 
0.141025641025641, 0.141025641025641, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0.0897435897435897, 0, 0.0897435897435897, 0, 0, 
1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.0897435897435897, 
0, 0, 0, 0.0897435897435897, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0.0897435897435897, 
0.0897435897435897, 0.0897435897435897, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.0897435897435897, 
0, 0, 0.0897435897435897, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0.0897435897435897, 
0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.0897435897435897, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 1, 0, 0, 0.0897435897435897, 0, 0, 0, 0.0897435897435897, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.0897435897435897, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.0897435897435897, 0, 0, 0, 
1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0.0897435897435897, 0.0897435897435897, 
0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.121794871794872, 0, 0.121794871794872, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.121794871794872, 
0, 0, 0, 0.121794871794872, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0.121794871794872, 
0.121794871794872, 0.121794871794872, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0.121794871794872, 
0, 0, 0.121794871794872, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0.121794871794872, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0.121794871794872, 0, 0, 0, 1, 
0, 1, 0, 1, 0.121794871794872, 0, 0, 0, 0.121794871794872, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.121794871794872, 
1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0.121794871794872, 0, 0, 0, 
1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0.121794871794872, 0.121794871794872, 
0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.115384615384615, 0, 0.115384615384615, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.115384615384615, 
0, 0, 0, 0.115384615384615, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0.115384615384615, 
0.115384615384615, 0.115384615384615, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.115384615384615, 
0, 0, 0.115384615384615, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0.115384615384615, 
0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.115384615384615, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0.115384615384615, 0, 0, 0, 0.115384615384615, 0, 
0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0.115384615384615, 
0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.115384615384615, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.115384615384615, 0.115384615384615, 
0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0.0506329113924051, 
0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.0506329113924051, 
0, 0, 0, 0.0506329113924051, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0.0506329113924051, 
0.0506329113924051, 0.0506329113924051, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.0506329113924051, 
0, 0, 0.0506329113924051, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 
1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.0506329113924051, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0.0506329113924051, 0, 0, 0, 0.0506329113924051, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.0506329113924051, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.0506329113924051, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0.0506329113924051, 0.0506329113924051, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0.0961538461538462, 0, 0.0961538461538462, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0.0961538461538462, 
0, 0, 0, 0.0961538461538462, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0.0961538461538462, 
0.0961538461538462, 0.0961538461538462, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.0961538461538462, 
0, 0, 0.0961538461538462, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.0961538461538462, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0.0961538461538462, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0.0961538461538462, 0, 0, 0, 0.0961538461538462, 
0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.0961538461538462, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.0961538461538462, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.0961538461538462, 0.0961538461538462, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 
1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0.0448717948717949, 0, 0.0448717948717949, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.0448717948717949, 
0, 0, 0, 0.0448717948717949, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.0448717948717949, 
0.0448717948717949, 0.0448717948717949, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.0448717948717949, 
0, 0, 0.0448717948717949, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.0448717948717949, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0.0448717948717949, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 1, 0, 0.0448717948717949, 0, 0, 0, 0.0448717948717949, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.0448717948717949, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.0448717948717949, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.0448717948717949, 0.0448717948717949, 
0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.0448717948717949, 0, 0.0448717948717949, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.0448717948717949, 
0, 0, 0, 0.0448717948717949, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.0448717948717949, 
0.0448717948717949, 0.0448717948717949, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0.0448717948717949, 
0, 0, 0.0448717948717949, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.0448717948717949, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.0448717948717949, 0, 0, 1, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0.0448717948717949, 1, 0, 0, 0.0448717948717949, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0.0448717948717949, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.0448717948717949, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0.0448717948717949, 0.0448717948717949, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), .Dim = c(173L, 31L), .Dimnames = list(
    c("TCGA-AB-2803", "TCGA-AB-2805", "TCGA-AB-2806", "TCGA-AB-2807", 
    "TCGA-AB-2808", "TCGA-AB-2810", "TCGA-AB-2811", "TCGA-AB-2812", 
    "TCGA-AB-2813", "TCGA-AB-2814", "TCGA-AB-2815", "TCGA-AB-2816", 
    "TCGA-AB-2817", "TCGA-AB-2818", "TCGA-AB-2819", "TCGA-AB-2820", 
    "TCGA-AB-2821", "TCGA-AB-2822", "TCGA-AB-2823", "TCGA-AB-2824", 
    "TCGA-AB-2825", "TCGA-AB-2826", "TCGA-AB-2828", "TCGA-AB-2830", 
    "TCGA-AB-2832", "TCGA-AB-2833", "TCGA-AB-2834", "TCGA-AB-2835", 
    "TCGA-AB-2836", "TCGA-AB-2837", "TCGA-AB-2838", "TCGA-AB-2839", 
    "TCGA-AB-2840", "TCGA-AB-2841", "TCGA-AB-2842", "TCGA-AB-2843", 
    "TCGA-AB-2844", "TCGA-AB-2845", "TCGA-AB-2846", "TCGA-AB-2847", 
    "TCGA-AB-2848", "TCGA-AB-2849", "TCGA-AB-2851", "TCGA-AB-2853", 
    "TCGA-AB-2854", "TCGA-AB-2855", "TCGA-AB-2856", "TCGA-AB-2857", 
    "TCGA-AB-2858", "TCGA-AB-2859", "TCGA-AB-2860", "TCGA-AB-2861", 
    "TCGA-AB-2862", "TCGA-AB-2863", "TCGA-AB-2865", "TCGA-AB-2866", 
    "TCGA-AB-2867", "TCGA-AB-2868", "TCGA-AB-2869", "TCGA-AB-2870", 
    "TCGA-AB-2871", "TCGA-AB-2872", "TCGA-AB-2873", "TCGA-AB-2874", 
    "TCGA-AB-2875", "TCGA-AB-2877", "TCGA-AB-2879", "TCGA-AB-2880", 
    "TCGA-AB-2881", "TCGA-AB-2882", "TCGA-AB-2884", "TCGA-AB-2885", 
    "TCGA-AB-2886", "TCGA-AB-2887", "TCGA-AB-2888", "TCGA-AB-2889", 
    "TCGA-AB-2890", "TCGA-AB-2891", "TCGA-AB-2895", "TCGA-AB-2896", 
    "TCGA-AB-2897", "TCGA-AB-2898", "TCGA-AB-2899", "TCGA-AB-2900", 
    "TCGA-AB-2901", "TCGA-AB-2903", "TCGA-AB-2904", "TCGA-AB-2908", 
    "TCGA-AB-2909", "TCGA-AB-2910", "TCGA-AB-2911", "TCGA-AB-2912", 
    "TCGA-AB-2913", "TCGA-AB-2914", "TCGA-AB-2915", "TCGA-AB-2916", 
    "TCGA-AB-2917", "TCGA-AB-2918", "TCGA-AB-2919", "TCGA-AB-2920", 
    "TCGA-AB-2921", "TCGA-AB-2924", "TCGA-AB-2925", "TCGA-AB-2927", 
    "TCGA-AB-2928", "TCGA-AB-2929", "TCGA-AB-2930", "TCGA-AB-2931", 
    "TCGA-AB-2932", "TCGA-AB-2933", "TCGA-AB-2934", "TCGA-AB-2935", 
    "TCGA-AB-2936", "TCGA-AB-2937", "TCGA-AB-2938", "TCGA-AB-2939", 
    "TCGA-AB-2940", "TCGA-AB-2941", "TCGA-AB-2942", "TCGA-AB-2943", 
    "TCGA-AB-2944", "TCGA-AB-2946", "TCGA-AB-2948", "TCGA-AB-2949", 
    "TCGA-AB-2950", "TCGA-AB-2952", "TCGA-AB-2954", "TCGA-AB-2955", 
    "TCGA-AB-2956", "TCGA-AB-2959", "TCGA-AB-2963", "TCGA-AB-2964", 
    "TCGA-AB-2965", "TCGA-AB-2966", "TCGA-AB-2967", "TCGA-AB-2969", 
    "TCGA-AB-2970", "TCGA-AB-2971", "TCGA-AB-2972", "TCGA-AB-2973", 
    "TCGA-AB-2975", "TCGA-AB-2976", "TCGA-AB-2977", "TCGA-AB-2978", 
    "TCGA-AB-2979", "TCGA-AB-2980", "TCGA-AB-2981", "TCGA-AB-2982", 
    "TCGA-AB-2983", "TCGA-AB-2984", "TCGA-AB-2985", "TCGA-AB-2986", 
    "TCGA-AB-2987", "TCGA-AB-2988", "TCGA-AB-2990", "TCGA-AB-2991", 
    "TCGA-AB-2992", "TCGA-AB-2993", "TCGA-AB-2994", "TCGA-AB-2995", 
    "TCGA-AB-2996", "TCGA-AB-2998", "TCGA-AB-2999", "TCGA-AB-3000", 
    "TCGA-AB-3001", "TCGA-AB-3002", "TCGA-AB-3005", "TCGA-AB-3006", 
    "TCGA-AB-3007", "TCGA-AB-3008", "TCGA-AB-3009", "TCGA-AB-3011", 
    "TCGA-AB-3012"), c("Offset", "CEBPA", "DNMT3A", "FAM5C", 
    "FLT3_ITD", "FLT3_TKD", "IDH1", "IDH2", "KIT", "KRAS", "NPM1", 
    "NRAS", "PHF6", "PTPN11", "RAD21", "RUNX1", "SMC1A", "SMC3", 
    "STAG2", "TET2", "TP53", "U2AF1", "WT1", "complex", "minus5_5q", 
    "minus7q", "plus8_8q", "plus21", "t_15_17", "t_8_21", "inv16_t16_16"
    )))
```

Comment: got an answer to start https://www.biostars.org/p/9533929/#9533942

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A design matrix is a matrix of values of the grouping variable.

ANOVA needs such a matrix to know which samples belong to which group. Since `limma` performs an ANOVA it needs this design matrix.

1. You can create it using the `model.matrix()` method.
2. Afterwards you can tell `limma` which groups you want to compare.

For point 2 you define a contrast matrix defining the comparisons of interest by using the `makeContrasts()` method.

It is well explained in this [manual's](https://www.bioconductor.org/packages/devel/bioc/vignettes/limma/inst/doc/usersguide.pdf) section 9.2